# XCode 4.3 Singletons

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton

So i just switched from xcode 4.2 to 4.3 and now my old way of creating/using singletons doesnt work. So i did my research on how to set up a singleton and i have this code here.

GlobalLogin.h

```
@interface GlobalLogin : UIViewController
+(GlobalLogin *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

GlobalLogin.m

```
@implementation GlobalLogin


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (GlobalLogin*)sharedInstance {

static GlobalLogin * sharedInstance;
if(!sharedInstance) {
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    });
}

return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    

return [self sharedInstance];
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;    
}

#if (!__has_feature(objc_arc))

- (id)retain {  

return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release {
//do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease {

return self;    
 }
#endif

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Custom Methods
```

So i have all that okay, but my problem is i cant find anywhere how to access its information in the various view controllers that need to use it. So if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you would call `+[super alloc]`, which should already basically be called by alloc itself, but I think you meant `-[super init]`, which even in itself should already by called by `-init`.  Change your initializer to read

```
static GlobalLogin * sharedInstance;
if(!sharedInstance) {
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
}
```

Then override `-init` and call super:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       //initialization code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: thank you thank you. How do you access it on the view controllers to alter/receive the info though? In the older xcode it was something simple like:

    GlobalLogin *global = [PlayersGlobal sharedUser];

but now that doesnt work

Comment: You need to send the correct class the `sharedUser` message, so it should read `GlobalLogin *global = [GlobalLogin sharedUser];`  Of course, there is no reason for this thing to be a UIViewController if you aren't going to display it (they can be quite expensive).

Comment: after i use the code to access the singleton how to i access like say a nsstring? i just tried global.--stringName-- = anotherstring; but that isn't working out so well for me.

Comment: Make it a property of the singleton and access the singleton like this: `NSString *myString = [GlobalLogin sharedUser].string;`

Comment: Because you named the method +sharedInstance.